# Fill SVG from bottom right to top left

Tags: html, animation, svg

I am trying to create a animation that fills my SVG from bottom right to top left after 2 seconds, what I have now is that it fills from right to left right when the page loads:

```html
<div id="home" class="section" style="height:100vh;background:pink;">
    <div class="background">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1366 768">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="a" transform="translate(7)">
                    <rect class="a" width="1366" height="768" />
                </clipPath>
                <linearGradient id="animation">
                    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffffff">
                        <animate dur="1s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" begin="2.5s;" />
                    </stop>
                    <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(0,0,0,0)">
                        <animate attributeName="offset" from="0" to="1" />
                    </stop>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <g id="line">
                <path class="c" fill="url(#animation)" d="M-7,0V768H1027.27l3.28-5.74c-3.1-5-4.9-11.68-6.45-15.93a5,5,0,0,1-.31-1.8c-.59-.57-1.19-1.12-1.77-1.71-4.19-4.3-8.13-8.78-12.31-13a5.41,5.41,0,0,1-2.41-1.24c-4-3.5-7.81-7.21-11.48-11-5.46-4.43-11-8.81-16.38-13.28-4.44-3.66-8.52-7.74-12.59-11.83l-1-1c-6.4-4.7-12.8-10.09-17.69-16.33-3.17-2.59-6.44-5.07-9.84-7.37-6.36-4.28-13.79-6.62-20.08-11-6.63-4.57-10.46-11.16-13.91-18.25A55.54,55.54,0,0,0,889,619.33c-6.11-5.14-12.61-9.88-18.16-15.64a78,78,0,0,1-12.74-18.42c-7.73-14.85-12.53-30.54-10.76-47.38,1.9-18,8.79-34.68,13.49-52,1.5-5.52,3.18-10.45,6.24-14.93a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,1.46-2c.62-.76,1.28-1.51,2-2.25,1.74-1.78,3.61-3.39,5.52-5,2.54-8.39,5.63-16.95,11.57-22.85s14.36-8.35,21.46-12.53l3.7-3.57a5.36,5.36,0,0,1,2.39-5.47l6-4,.13-.08a5.88,5.88,0,0,1,.86-1.14l.3-.28a56.64,56.64,0,0,1,6.64-8.71,65.33,65.33,0,0,1,12.5-9.54,117.79,117.79,0,0,1,21.82-11.11c2.33-2.18,4.67-4.3,7-6.36a5.65,5.65,0,0,1,1.71-1.05c10.21-9.09,20.39-18.22,30.84-27,23.11-19.45,53.32-31.79,67.9-59.69,3.29-6.31,5.61-13.11,9.27-19.24a42.87,42.87,0,0,1,8.74-10.4,4.6,4.6,0,0,1,1.48-3.27c12.36-12.17,26.31-22.61,38.52-35,9.54-9.64,17.38-20.78,26.94-30.43a125.77,125.77,0,0,1,28.08-21.42,5.51,5.51,0,0,1,3.16-3.15,78.09,78.09,0,0,1,8.24-2.51c24.36-10.73,51.73-14.36,78.2-11.67l.37.06a4.68,4.68,0,0,1,3.1-1.06,4.55,4.55,0,0,1,4.55,3.25c14-.7,28.06-1.53,41.63,1.59A41,41,0,0,1,1351,176.34a108.65,108.65,0,0,1,10.4,6.73L1366,175V0Z"
                    transform="translate(7)" />
                <path class="d" d="M1034.5,770.5a125.59,125.59,0,0,0-17-32c-12.32-16.72-25.68-25.84-33-31-6-4.23-59.88-42.55-100-90-13.64-16.14-20.57-24.48-26-38-15-37.48-3.73-73.65,0-85,8.68-26.45,23-43.26,35-57,19-21.82,33.56-29.9,67-54,33.68-24.27,55.39-39.91,77-60,40.56-37.69,35.94-49.35,81-96,34.18-35.39,51.27-53.08,79-65,7.79-3.35,76-31.44,140,2a142.06,142.06,0,0,1,31,22l7.5,7.5"
                    transform="translate(7)" />
            </g>
            <polyline class="c" points="1373 175 1373 184.22 1370.37 179.61" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that it fills from bottom right to top left after 2 seconds?

Comment: use the x1, x2, y1, and y2 attributes of your linearGradient ?

Comment: I have played around with these values but I can't seem to get them right

Comment: `x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%"` basically, first point top left corner, second one bottom right corner. https://jsfiddle.net/bwLp6ok5/

Comment: Thank you, do you know what I have to look into to start the animation after 2 seconds?

Comment: [The docs...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

begin changes the animation start time and set the initial offset to be the same as the start animation value as the animation won't apply before its start time.

You can either adjust x1, y1, x2, y2 of the gradient or set gradientTransform="rotate(45)" though you'd probably want a scale transform too as the shape you're filling isn't square.

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1366 768">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="a" transform="translate(7)">
                <rect class="a" width="1366" height="768" />
            </clipPath>
            <linearGradient id="animation" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%">
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#580073">
                    <animate dur="2s" begin="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" />
                </stop>
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff">
                    <animate dur="2s" begin="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="1" to="0" />
                </stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <g id="line">
            <path class="c" fill="url(#animation)" d="M-7,0V768H1027.27l3.28-5.74c-3.1-5-4.9-11.68-6.45-15.93a5,5,0,0,1-.31-1.8c-.59-.57-1.19-1.12-1.77-1.71-4.19-4.3-8.13-8.78-12.31-13a5.41,5.41,0,0,1-2.41-1.24c-4-3.5-7.81-7.21-11.48-11-5.46-4.43-11-8.81-16.38-13.28-4.44-3.66-8.52-7.74-12.59-11.83l-1-1c-6.4-4.7-12.8-10.09-17.69-16.33-3.17-2.59-6.44-5.07-9.84-7.37-6.36-4.28-13.79-6.62-20.08-11-6.63-4.57-10.46-11.16-13.91-18.25A55.54,55.54,0,0,0,889,619.33c-6.11-5.14-12.61-9.88-18.16-15.64a78,78,0,0,1-12.74-18.42c-7.73-14.85-12.53-30.54-10.76-47.38,1.9-18,8.79-34.68,13.49-52,1.5-5.52,3.18-10.45,6.24-14.93a5.66,5.66,0,0,1,1.46-2c.62-.76,1.28-1.51,2-2.25,1.74-1.78,3.61-3.39,5.52-5,2.54-8.39,5.63-16.95,11.57-22.85s14.36-8.35,21.46-12.53l3.7-3.57a5.36,5.36,0,0,1,2.39-5.47l6-4,.13-.08a5.88,5.88,0,0,1,.86-1.14l.3-.28a56.64,56.64,0,0,1,6.64-8.71,65.33,65.33,0,0,1,12.5-9.54,117.79,117.79,0,0,1,21.82-11.11c2.33-2.18,4.67-4.3,7-6.36a5.65,5.65,0,0,1,1.71-1.05c10.21-9.09,20.39-18.22,30.84-27,23.11-19.45,53.32-31.79,67.9-59.69,3.29-6.31,5.61-13.11,9.27-19.24a42.87,42.87,0,0,1,8.74-10.4,4.6,4.6,0,0,1,1.48-3.27c12.36-12.17,26.31-22.61,38.52-35,9.54-9.64,17.38-20.78,26.94-30.43a125.77,125.77,0,0,1,28.08-21.42,5.51,5.51,0,0,1,3.16-3.15,78.09,78.09,0,0,1,8.24-2.51c24.36-10.73,51.73-14.36,78.2-11.67l.37.06a4.68,4.68,0,0,1,3.1-1.06,4.55,4.55,0,0,1,4.55,3.25c14-.7,28.06-1.53,41.63,1.59A41,41,0,0,1,1351,176.34a108.65,108.65,0,0,1,10.4,6.73L1366,175V0Z"
                transform="translate(7)" />
            <path class="d" d="M1034.5,770.5a125.59,125.59,0,0,0-17-32c-12.32-16.72-25.68-25.84-33-31-6-4.23-59.88-42.55-100-90-13.64-16.14-20.57-24.48-26-38-15-37.48-3.73-73.65,0-85,8.68-26.45,23-43.26,35-57,19-21.82,33.56-29.9,67-54,33.68-24.27,55.39-39.91,77-60,40.56-37.69,35.94-49.35,81-96,34.18-35.39,51.27-53.08,79-65,7.79-3.35,76-31.44,140,2a142.06,142.06,0,0,1,31,22l7.5,7.5"
                transform="translate(7)" />
        </g>
        <polyline class="c" points="1373 175 1373 184.22 1370.37 179.61" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: I noticed that the square fill did not look that good, could you show me how I could fill with the right shape?

Comment: Oops, I have edited my question, as you can see the white part fills with sharp corners, is there a way to adjust that?

Comment: Sorry, I have reverted the changes and will ask a new question, thanks for the answer

Comment: I have asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52590530/responsive-svg-fill-shape with some more details