# Responsive SVG fill shape

Tags: html, animation, svg, linear-gradients

```css
#fg {
  fill: url(#ship);
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1024px;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s;
  animation: dash 2s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1024px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1024px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
  }
}

#bg {
  fill: white;
  stroke: none;
  transform-origin: 1270px 550px;
  -webkit-animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
  animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes bgfill {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgfill {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}
#home {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yB6Tc3mleuE/T4NkAKeazYI/AAAAAAAACB0/tlichKzIu3Q/s1600/Simple+unique+odd+weird+wallpapers+minimalistic+%2330+battleship+titanic.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div class="background">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1376 764">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="ship">
                    <use xlink:href="#shape" id="bg" />
                </clipPath>
                <path id="shape" d="M1034.5,770.5a125.59,125.59,0,0,0-17-32c-12.32-16.72-25.68-25.84-33-31-6-4.23-59.88-42.55-100-90-13.64-16.14-20.57-24.48-26-38-15-37.48-3.73-73.65,0-85,8.68-26.45,23-43.26,35-57,19-21.82,33.56-29.9,67-54,33.68-24.27,55.39-39.91,77-60,40.56-37.69,35.94-49.35,81-96,34.18-35.39,51.27-53.08,79-65,7.79-3.35,76-31.44,140,2a142.06,142.06,0,0,1,31,22l7.5,7.5  L 1376,770.5 Z" />
            </defs>
            <image xlink:href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yB6Tc3mleuE/T4NkAKeazYI/AAAAAAAACB0/tlichKzIu3Q/s1600/Simple+unique+odd+weird+wallpapers+minimalistic+%2330+battleship+titanic.jpg"
                width="1376" height="764" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#ship)" />
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="fg" />
        </svg>
    </div>
```

I am trying to create a page load animation, first the white line gets drawn and afterwards I want to fill the screen with a white SVG animation, I got everything to work but I do not like the sharp edge for the fill effect, how can I change the shape of the corner to the shape of the white line? please see the animation in action to get a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your original path shape and grow (scale) that.

For the following example, I removed the unnecessary elements you were using, and modified the main shape slightly so that it had a bottom right corner (instead of just being the line), so I could fill it.

I put one copy in front (id="fg"), with a dash animation as you requested in a previous question.  And behind it, I put a copy of the path (id="bg") with a white fill.  Then when the dash animation finishes, I start a second animation that scales the white version of the shape up by 4x to fill the SVG.

```css
#fg {
  fill: pink;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1024px;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s;
          animation: dash 2s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1024px; }
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1024px; }
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
}


#bg {
  fill: white;
  stroke: none;
  transform-origin: 1270px 550px;
  -webkit-animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
          animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes bgfill {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to   { transform: scale(4); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgfill {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to   { transform: scale(4); }
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section" style="height:100vh;background:pink;">
    <div class="background">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1376 764">
            <defs>
                <path id="shape" d="M1034.5,770.5a125.59,125.59,0,0,0-17-32c-12.32-16.72-25.68-25.84-33-31-6-4.23-59.88-42.55-100-90-13.64-16.14-20.57-24.48-26-38-15-37.48-3.73-73.65,0-85,8.68-26.45,23-43.26,35-57,19-21.82,33.56-29.9,67-54,33.68-24.27,55.39-39.91,77-60,40.56-37.69,35.94-49.35,81-96,34.18-35.39,51.27-53.08,79-65,7.79-3.35,76-31.44,140,2a142.06,142.06,0,0,1,31,22l7.5,7.5  L 1376,770.5 Z"/>
            </defs>
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="bg"/>
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="fg"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

To have the background fill with an image, the simplest approach is probably by using a clip path.

```css
#fg {
  fill: pink;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 1028px;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s;
          animation: dash 2s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1028px; }
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1028px; }
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
}


#bg {
  fill: url(#kitten);
  stroke: none;
  transform-origin: 1270px 550px;
  -webkit-animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
          animation: bgfill 2s linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes bgfill {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to   { transform: scale(4); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgfill {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to   { transform: scale(4); }
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section" style="height:100vh;background:pink;">
    <div class="background">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1376 764">
            <defs>
                <path id="shape" d="M1034.5,770.5a125.59,125.59,0,0,0-17-32c-12.32-16.72-25.68-25.84-33-31-6-4.23-59.88-42.55-100-90-13.64-16.14-20.57-24.48-26-38-15-37.48-3.73-73.65,0-85,8.68-26.45,23-43.26,35-57,19-21.82,33.56-29.9,67-54,33.68-24.27,55.39-39.91,77-60,40.56-37.69,35.94-49.35,81-96,34.18-35.39,51.27-53.08,79-65,7.79-3.35,76-31.44,140,2a142.06,142.06,0,0,1,31,22l7.5,7.5  L 1376,770.5 Z"/>
                <clipPath id="kitten">
                  <use xlink:href="#shape" id="bg"/>
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
            <image xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/700/350" width="1376" height="764" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#kitten)"/>
            <use xlink:href="#shape" id="fg"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice way and without JavaScript as well, I will try to get rid of the line that's always there though because first a full screen image will be visible

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: So after playing around with this I noticed a problem, in my example I used a background color while my plan was to use a background image, with this approach I would not be able to use one because the shapes appear on top of the image

Comment: Just make the "bg" shape into a clipPath or mask. Or you could turn the background image into a `<pattern>` fill for the shape.

Comment: Could you show me the clipPath/mask method? I would appreciate it

Comment: Okay. I have added an example of how to use a clip path instead.

Comment: But this still shows the pink part, I am basically trying to achieve so that the line appears on top of the image and then the white fills from the line to the top left so that only the bottom right part of the image is visible at the end and the rest of the page is white

Comment: I've shown you how a clip path works now. And it should be fairly obvious now how to modify my first example to do what you want. How about having a go yourself and seeing if you can do it?  Hint: apply the clip to "fg" between the first and second animations.

Comment: I have edited the code, I came so far, the SVG HTML markup looks very abstract to me and I found myself puzzling towards the end by trying out different combinations, I couldn't get the white fill to work but the image displays properly

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting the comments in, this took me way too long now but I can finally finish my site, will save it for future reference